# Visualizar em real time todas as scripts PHP em execução via SSH

Tags: php, ssh

Tenho algumas scripts que fazem um trabalho de data mining, e em alguns casos precisam rodar longos processos que podem consumir muita CPU. Preciso descobrir um comando via SSH para monitorar todas as scripts PHP em execução.
Algo do tipo:

```
watch ps -F -C php-cgi ...
```

mas para mim não funciona.

Comment: Depende de muitos fatores. Quando executa sob um webserver, Apache, por exemplo, será exibido o processo "httpd". Quando roda via CLI, é exibido o path do compilador e não o arquivo que foi invocado. Para um maior controle, procure sobre signal handler:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php. Apenas esteja ciente de que funções `pcntl` usam `POSIX`, por isso não funciona sob ambiente Windows. Consulte também http://php.net/manual/en/event.addsignal.php. Sem tempo para postar como resposta. Pois exige uma resposta relativamente longa.

Comment: @Eduardo você está rodando os PHPs standalone (via shell)? No `ps- aux` você enxerga os processos separadamente?

Comment: Os scripts são executados em background usando o `&`? Caso sim, você pode usar o comando `jobs` ou `jobs -l` para listar o comandos rodando no background.

Comment: watch ps u -u USUÁRIO_NOME * Quantos script php sendo utilizado
* Memória e CPU utilizado [Agora se tudo que você deseja é "Espionar" um processo existente.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session?answertab=active#tab-top)